# Value of java.lang.String cannot be converted to double

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I have a PHP web service whill pulls data out of a MySQL database.

I have an Android app which calls the service.

Locally on my WAMP Server everything works fine but I just uploaded the data/service to a domain and testing against that.

I am getting this error:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value  at Latitude of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to double
```

From this line of code:

```
double latitude = thisVenue.getDouble(TAG_LATITUDE);
```

And the value (taking from the log via Android Studio) which causes this error is:

```
"Latitude":"51.05279"
```

I cannot see why that value cannot be converted to a double. Locally my app can parse the same dataset no problem so I presume it has something to do with how it is stored/retrieved?

Edit: Here is one of the objects returned in JSON, notice all values have quotes

```
{"VenueID":"4","ListingID":"19","Name":"TempName1","Location":"207 10A St NW","DayOfWeek":"Mon","Featured":"0","FeaturedDistanceRange":"0","Latitude":"51.05279","Longitude":"-110.087509","StartHour":"4","StartHourType":"pm","StartMinute":"0","EndHour":"7","EndHourType":"pm","EndMinute":"0"}
```

And I format it as JSON like so:

```
    header("Content-type: application/json");
    print(json_encode(array('venues'=>$data)));
```

Comment: Take a peek here and check your chars... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13368739/jsonexception-value-of-type-java-lang-string-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonobject

Comment: This is standard JSON response. Everything comes back quoted

Answer (score 0):

As the data from the server is not a double, u must use as this

```
double latitude = Double.valueOf(thisVenue.getString(TAG_LATITUDE));
```

Comment: This causes a fatal exception. As I said everything in JSON comes back with quotes around it, even int fields

Comment: No, it is not, `"5.1"` is a string `5.1` is a double

Comment: @andrewb No. It isn't. It only works in JavaScript because of that language's type system.

Comment: Right but this works locally so why not on a domain?

Comment: And I am not using JavaScript, I am using PHP to output the dataset as JSON, and this wraps the data in quotes

Comment: The PHP type system does what now? Is your question PHP, or Java?

Comment: grrr, JS is not a type safe language ... and PHP ...well ...i don't wana start some flame

Comment: Android app is calling PHP web service. No JS whatsoever

Answer (score 0):

Check you are getting a valid double back from the getDouble() method (the compiler doesn't think you are. If the following compiles and throws a NumberfFormatException at runtime then you know you're not getting a valid double.
And "Latitude":"51.05279" doesn't look like a parseable double, "51.05279" would be fine.

```
double latitude = Double.parseDouble(thisVenue.getDouble(TAG_LATITUDE));
```

Comment: "Latitude" is the JSON key.I do get a NumberFormatException: Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""