# Listview doenst show all item from json

Tags: android, json, android-listview, android-asynctask, android-parser

I'm filling a lazy loaded listview with items from a Json and it only shows the first item, without the image, not showing the rest of the items. I'm using AsyncTask to load my items to my listview. Can somebody PLEASE help me solve this problem.

Here is my LatesAlbums class:

```
public class LatestAlbums extends FragmentActivity {

    // widgets
    private ListView list;
    private ImageView back, clear;
    private EditText find;

    private static String url = "jsonURL";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_ALBUMS = "albums";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_SINGER = "singer";
    private static final String TAG_GENRE = "genre";
    private static final String TAG_MIX = "mix";
    private static final String TAG_THUMB = "thumb";
    private static final String TAG_SONGS = "songs";
    private static final String TAG_SONG_TITLE = "song";
    private static final String TAG_SONG_ARTIST = "artist";
    private static final String TAG_SONG_MP3 = "mp3";
    private static final String TAG_SONG_MP4 = "mp4";
    private static final String TAG_SONG_THUMB = "thumb";
    private ProgressDialog pdialog;

    // albums JSONArray
    private JSONArray albums;
    private JSONArray sngs;

    private ArrayList<Albums> albumsArray;
    private ArrayList<Songs> songsArray;
    private AlbumLazyAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.latest_albums);
        albumsArray = new ArrayList<Albums>();
        songsArray = new ArrayList<Songs>();

        try {
            loadJSON();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // initWidgets();
    }

    private void initWidgets() {
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.latest_back_img);
        clear = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.latest_search_clear);
        clear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                find.setText("");
                find.clearFocus();
                find.clearComposingText();
                clear.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
        find = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.latest_search_et);
        back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        adapter = new AlbumLazyAdapter(this, albumsArray, this);

        // set list view adapter
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        // setting find edit text searching method
        find.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                clear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                for (int i = 0; i < albumsArray.size(); i++) {
                    if (albumsArray.get(i).getTAG_NAME().toLowerCase()
                            .indexOf(find.getText().toString().toLowerCase()) != -1) {
                        Log.v("--", albumsArray.get(i).getTAG_NAME());
                    } else {
                        Log.v("--", "no results..");
                    }
                }

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initWidgets();
    }

    // load json from server via asyncTask
    public void loadJSON() throws JSONException {
        AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                initWidgets();
                pdialog = new ProgressDialog(LatestAlbums.this);
                pdialog.setMessage("Loading ....");
                pdialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
                JSONObject theJSON;
                try {

                    // Getting Array of albums
                    theJSON = json.getJSONObject("json");
                    albums = theJSON.getJSONArray(TAG_ALBUMS);
                    // looping through All albums
                    for (int i = 0; i < albums.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = albums.getJSONObject(i);
                        String album_id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String album_name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String album_singer = c.getString(TAG_SINGER);
                        String album_mix = c.getString(TAG_MIX);
                        String album_genre = c.getString(TAG_GENRE);
                        String album_thumb = c.getString(TAG_THUMB);
                        albumsArray.add(new Albums(album_id, album_name,
                                album_singer, album_genre, album_mix,
                                album_thumb, songsArray));
                        sngs = c.getJSONArray(TAG_SONGS);
                        // getting songs for the album
                        if (!sngs.isNull(0)) {
                            for (int j = 0; j < sngs.length(); j++) {
                                JSONObject songs = sngs.getJSONObject(j);
                                String song_artist = songs
                                        .getString("artist");
                                String song_mp3 = songs.getString(TAG_SONG_MP3);
                                String song_mp4 = songs.getString(TAG_SONG_MP4);
                                String song_thumb = songs
                                        .getString(TAG_SONG_THUMB);
                                String song_title = songs
                                        .getString(TAG_SONG_TITLE);
                                songsArray.add(new Songs(song_title,
                                        song_artist, song_mp3, song_mp4,
                                        song_thumb));
                            }
                        }

                        albumsArray.get(i).setSongs(songsArray);
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                            int position, long arg3) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                                AlbumDetails.class);
                        i.putExtra("songs", albumsArray.get(position)
                                .getSongs());
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
                // setting the slider
                ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.my_slider);
                FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                MyFragmentPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(
                        fm, albumsArray);
                pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
                pdialog.dismiss();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
        task.execute();
    }
}
```

And my Json output:

```
{

    "json":{


        "albums":[{"id":"1","name":"Best Sumer colections","singer":"Dj Tiresto","genre":"Trance","mix":"yes","thumb":"alb1.png","songs":
                                            [
                                             {"song":"Nothins else1","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                                             {"song":"Nothins else2","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                                             {"song":"Nothins else3","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                                             {"song":"Nothins else4","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                                             {"song":"Nothins else5","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                                             {"song":"Nothins else6","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},


                                                                                                                                 ]
                  },
                  {"id":"2","name":"Best Sumer colections","singer":"Dj Tiresto","genre":"Trance","mix":"yes","thumb":"alb1.png","songs":
                  [
                   {"song":"Nothins else1","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else2","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else3","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else4","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else5","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else6","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},


                   ]
                  },
                  {"id":"3","name":"O viatza","singer":"Maria Bieshu","genre":"Trance","mix":"no","thumb":"alb1.png","songs":
                  [
                   {"song":"Nothins else1","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else2","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else3","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else4","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else5","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else6","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},


                   ]
                  },
                  {"id":"4","name":"De petrecere","singer":"Gerghe tzopa","genre":"Trance","mix":"no","thumb":"alb1.png","songs":
                  [
                   {"song":"Nothins else1","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else2","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else3","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else4","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else5","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else6","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},


                   ]
                  },
                  {"id":"5","name":"De petrecere","singer":"Gerghe tzopa","genre":"Trance","mix":"no","thumb":"alb1.png","songs":
                  [
                   {"song":"Nothins else1","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else2","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else3","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else4","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else5","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else6","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},


                   ]
                  },
                  {"id":"6","name":"De petrecere 2013","singer":"Gerghe tzopa","genre":"Trance","mix":"no","thumb":"alb1.png","songs":
                  [
                   {"song":"Nothins else1","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else2","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else3","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else4","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else5","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else6","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},


                   ]
                  }

        ]


    }


}
```

LogCat output:

```
04-02 13:35:12.109: W/System.err(12798): org.json.JSONException: Value at 6 is null.
04-02 13:35:12.119: W/System.err(12798):    at org.json.JSONArray.get(JSONArray.java:259)
04-02 13:35:12.119: W/System.err(12798):    at org.json.JSONArray.getJSONObject(JSONArray.java:480)
04-02 13:35:12.119: W/System.err(12798):    at com.outsourcefarm.musicagratis.activities.LatestAlbums$4.doInBackground(LatestAlbums.java:188)
04-02 13:35:12.119: W/System.err(12798):    at com.outsourcefarm.musicagratis.activities.LatestAlbums$4.doInBackground(LatestAlbums.java:1)
04-02 13:35:12.119: W/System.err(12798):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
04-02 13:35:12.119: W/System.err(12798):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
04-02 13:35:12.119: W/System.err(12798):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-02 13:35:12.129: W/System.err(12798):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
04-02 13:35:12.129: W/System.err(12798):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
04-02 13:35:12.129: W/System.err(12798):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
04-02 13:35:12.129: W/System.err(12798):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Line 188 is `JSONObject songs = sngs.getJSONObject(j);`

Comment: Image URLs are not real, even MP3 and MP4 URLs are also not real.

Comment: @PareshMayani url,mp3 and mp4 are read as string in this activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems everything was ok, for those that will have similar problem but make sure that in the json class, or for more explanation look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267910/jsonexception-value-of-type-java-lang-string-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonobject)

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
```

is set like this:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "UTF-8"), 8);
```