# Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value db_connect.php of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, php, android, json, eclipse

I don't know what is wrong with my app. Currently, I'm developing a restaurant finder application. For the database, I'm using PHP and mySQL. The data that I insert from the interface, is appeared in the database(localhost). However, the app keeps showing a message "The application RestFinder (process.com.example.restaurantfinder) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again." and then it crashed.

When I check the log file, the first log file is:

`Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value db_connect.php of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`

Can someone give me a solution for this?

these are the code for JSONParser.java that I suspected that caused the error.

```
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method, List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // check for request method
        if (method == "POST") {
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } else if(method == "GET") {
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json.substring(6));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;
}
```

Comment: Please show us the code that causes the error.

Comment: ...as well as the input.

Comment: Matt Ball : do you mean the snapshot?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your JSON data input that cause this exception.

You can also refer this solution from stockoverflow - [JSONException: Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267910/jsonexception-value-of-type-java-lang-string-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonobject)

Answer (score 0):

> db_connect.php of type java.lang.String

This here shows you that you are not the one doing something wrong (this time :D), the server is misconfigured, and you are getting an invalid response.

Please post the output of the URL specified to get this result, as well as the php script you are running.