# Android String cannot be converted to JSONObject(A different Error)

Tags: android, json

I am trying to parse JSON from web service. But i get "String could not be converted to Json Object" error.

My json: `{"encoding":"UTF-8","yorumlar":[["dogukan","deneme yorumu"],["Burak","yorum"]]}`
I get this string like below;

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse response = null;
            try
            {
                response = client.execute(request);
                String jsonString = StreamUtils.convertToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
                .
                .
                .
```

When i got this string from web service like above, i get this error but when i do that:

```
JsonObject object = new JsonObject("{\"encoding\":\"UTF-8\",\"yorumlar\":[[\"dogukan\",\"deneme yorumu\"],[\"Burak\",\"yorum\"]]}")
```

i don't get this error. So, the strings are the same and json format is ok. What is the problem?

Comment: did you debug and check what is "response" ?

Comment: are you sure you are getting the correct response? have you logged it?

Comment: Hey, Please print log for response and put here for clerify doubt. M here to help you.

Comment: Have you specified the **Content-Type** to **application/json** in your WS's answer ?

Comment: Yes, i debugged and copied the value of "jsonString". It was the same string. There is not any differences. @QuentinKlein
Yes Content-Type is application/json

Comment: Could there be some extra spaces in your string? Check this one:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267910/jsonexception-value-of-type-java-lang-string-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonobject

Comment: check the value for variable jsonString also.  Can try a normal convertToString with charset utf-8 [InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8")]

Comment: I can get json from youtube gdata in same method. There is no problem while parsing youtube data.

Comment: might be some character difference...compare the exact strings, encoding?

Comment: I am going to be crazy. I have no idea what is the problem. I have tried changing encoding and the other ways but still gives error. Strings are the same, i can get json from youtube response in the same method.

Comment: check all brackets, escape chars, post a logcat read of the time this happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, the json string starts with these characters "ï»¿ï»¿". But these characters does not appear in debug mode. I created a java project. And i got the json string from server. I saw these characters in debug mode. Java project gave me more details about the converting error.

if you try to get the values of these in debug mode:

jsonString.toCharArray()[0] and jsonString.toCharArray()[1]

you will see the values as "", not "{". It's not space but does not appear. and "{" character located in 2. index.

We have solved the problem on server side. I guess that was an page encoding problem.