# Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, json, http-post

In my code, I am trying to access some json return from server. But I can't convert json return from server to JsonObject. Here is my code,

```
result = post.getHttpData(Constants.UrlDepartureCity);
catchLog(result);
JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(result);
```

I use my custom catchLog to print json return in log.

```
09-23 14:53:59.940: I/DepartureCityAsync(23313): 
{"status":"1","departure_city":[
{"entity_id":"1","field_depature_city_tid":"1","entity_type":"node"},
{"entity_id":"8","field_depature_city_tid":"1","entity_type":"node"}, 
{"entity_id":"12","field_depature_city_tid":"1","entity_type":"node"},
{"entity_id":"5","field_depature_city_tid":"2","entity_type":"node"},
{"entity_id":"9","field_depature_city_tid":"2","entity_type":"node"},
{"entity_id":"17","field_depature_city_tid":"2","entity_type":"node"},
{"entity_id":"6","field_depature_city_tid":"3","entity_type":"node"},
{"entity_id":"7","field_depature_city_tid":"5","entity_type":"node"}]}
```

And I copy the result and validate that json return in http://jsonlint.com/. There is no error, syntax also correct. But When I try to convert it to JsonObject I got this error.

```
09-23 14:53:59.940: W/System.err(23313): org.json.JSONException: Value ﻿ of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

How can I solve this problem? Please.
Thanks

Comment: Write the code for catch log method

Comment: @ Rahul Gupta I already wrote the code for catch log

Comment: I mean the method catchLog(result), Its Implementation code. You are passing result in it

Answer (score 1):

I think there may be some blank characters in your return. Change it to 
JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(result.trim());

Comment: @SAWAUNG :) then please accept the answer and close the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think your json format is wrong or has some little mistake. From [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267910/jsonexception-value-of-type-java-lang-string-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonobject), you can find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
final TextView res=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.res);

    try
    {
        HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost request=new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.30/test.js");
        HttpResponse response=client.execute(request);
        HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
        res.setText(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        res.setText(e.toString());
    }
```

here is my code sample it works for me...for the same json as you provided.
can you show me your code how you get the response.i didn't get the method getHttpData() you've used.