# Android json to php and back

Tags: php, android, json

I am sending a `Json` representation of an `arraylist` of custom objects to the server.  I hope then to take that `json` object, decode into an array and retrieve the attributes and place them in `MySQL`.  I think I am having an encoding issue. My `php` source code is written in notepad++ and is endcoded to `utf-8`.  I believe Android encodes its source code and SQlite Datavabe in utf-8.  The data that i use to construct the `arraylist` of my custom objects comes from `SQLite`.

When i `POST` a `json` object of my custom `arraylist` on the browser, the `json` is read successfully.  However, when i send it via my android I get the error below. Someone please help?

**Android code:**

```
ArrayList<Article> list;
   list = recallSharedListFromDb();

    // Create json
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    String json_arrayList = gson.toJson(list);
        // Build parameters. 
        List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("jsonObj", json_object));

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_register_code, "POST", param);

        // Read json response coming from server.
        Log.d("SyncToMySQL", "json string: "+ json.toString());
```

**Php code:**

> //Get JSON posted by Android Application
>        $json = $_POST["jsonObj"]; // this works...
>        //Decode JSON into an Array
>        $data = json_decode($json);

```
 $num_objects = count($data);

if($data){
$response["number of objects"] = $num_objects;
$response["success"] = 1;
echo $json. "<br><br>";;
 }else{
$response["number of objects"] = 0;
$response["success"] = 0;
 }

echo json_encode($response);
```

**StackTrace:**

> ```
>   12-31 09:54:59.966: E/JSON Parser(1826): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value (STRANGE LOOKING SYMBOLS) of    type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObjec
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Missing header before sending data:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);;
```

Comment: Could you please log this json respone with: Log.d("JSON: ", json.toString()); and paste it here.

Comment: 12-31 10:47:41.726: D/SyncToMySQL(1826): json string: {"number of objects":0,"success":0}

Comment: Did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11734642/751387 - i think you have same issue

Comment: And also try: header('Content-type=application/json; charset=utf-8');

Comment: i am still getting the same error. I am still getting the strange symbols where i indicated in the above stacktrace " STRANGE LOOKING SYMBOLS"

Comment: they are the symbols that i am getting. the one in the image. top row.  I will look into the article.

Answer (score 0):

Add `header('Content-type: application/json');` before sending json, like this

```
$num_objects = count($data);

if($data){
$response["number of objects"] = $num_objects;
$response["success"] = 1;
echo $json. "<br><br>";;
 }else{
$response["number of objects"] = 0;
$response["success"] = 0;
 }

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```