# i m trying to get response from server and retrieving it using JSON. java.lang.string cannot be convert into jsonObject

Tags: java, android, json, string, object

i m trying to get response from server and retrieving it using JSON everything is going great without any error but my IF statement is not executing, program is jumping on other execution task, when i debug my app it says that java.lang.string cannot be converted to jsonObject that's why it is not executing it.... i m new in this programming and it is my first application. I hope anyone can help me please. i m attaching my BackgroundTask.java and server response, if anything else is needed please tell me.

**BackgroundTask.java**:

```
'package in.co.medimap.www.myfirstapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.EditText;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.google.gson.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

/**
* Created by sony on 29-04-2016.
*/
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
{
    String register_url = "http://192.168.42.14/loginapp/register.php";
    String login_url = "http://192.168.42.14/loginapp/login.php";
    String json;
    JSONArray peoples;
    Context ctx;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    Activity activity;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;

    public BackgroundTask(Context ctx)
    {
        this.ctx=ctx;
        activity = (Activity)ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        builder  = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Connecting to server .... ");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        String method = params[0];
        if (method.equals("register")) {
            try 
            {
                URL url = new URL(register_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream=httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
                String owner_name = params[1];
                String shop_name = params[2];
                String phone_no = params[3];
                String shop_address=params[4];
                String password=params[5];
                String data = URLEncoder.encode("owner_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(owner_name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("shop_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(shop_name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("phone_no","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(phone_no,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("shop_address","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(shop_address,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line = "";
                while ((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
                {
                    stringBuilder.append(line+"\n");
                }
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                return  stringBuilder.toString().trim();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else if(method.equals("login"))
        {
            try
            {
                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream=httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
                String phone_no,password;
                phone_no=params[1];
                password=params[2];
                String data =URLEncoder.encode("phone_no","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(phone_no,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                             URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line="";
                while ((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
                {
                    stringBuilder.append(line+"\n");
                }
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                return stringBuilder.toString().trim();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String json)
    {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        try
        {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            peoples = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");
            JSONObject JO = peoples.getJSONObject(0);
            String code = JO.getString("code");
            String message = JO.getString("message");
    //problem starts from here
            if (code.equals("reg_true"))
            {
                showDialog("Registration Success", code, message);
            }
            else if (code.equals("reg_false")) {
                showDialog("Registration Failed", code, message);
            }
            else if (code.equals("login_true")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(activity, HomeActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("message", message);
                activitcode.equals("login_false")) {
                    showDialog("Login Error...",code, message);
                }
            }
    //IF statement is not executing due to java.lang.string cannot be converted    into jsonObject
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void showDialog(String title, String code, String message)
    {
        builder.setTitle(title);
        if(code.equals("reg_true")||code.equals("reg_false"))
        {
            builder.setMessage(message);
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    activity.finish();
                }
            });
        }
        else if (code.equals("login_false")) {
            builder.setMessage(message);
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    EditText phone_no, password;
                    phone_no = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.phone_no);
                    password = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.password);
                    phone_no.setText("");
                    password.setText("");
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
       AlertDialog alertDialog =builder.create();
       alertDialog.show();
    }
}

//server response for registration success

{"server_response":[{"code":"reg_true","0":"message=>Registration    Success...Thank you....."}]}
```

Comment: I did not see your code but you will get this error only when string contains wrong json object

Comment: Log your string before parsing to you can see it

Comment: improved formating

Comment: can u please edit my coding into correct one ?

Answer (score 0):

i made a similar application and this worked me. Hope this helps

[JSONException: Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267910/jsonexception-value-of-type-java-lang-string-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonobject)

Comment: can you please edit my code and tell me exactly where is problem, it'll be nice thankyou

Comment: Try with this, where you return de json or on the json exception ....  This  will remove unwanted strings

return new JSONObject(json.substring(json.indexOf("{"), json.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));

Comment: it will be better if you tell me how to do it using GSON

Comment: can u plz edit my wrong coding part and post it please ... ill. paste it and try it thnk you