# JSONException: Value .<!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject error

Tags: php, android, json, parsing, android-studio

I have looked for solutions online on what I might be doing wrong but I am unable to find my mistake. The php works fine so am not sure what I am doing wrong. Please help! Here is my php.

```
      <?php 

      if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){

      $Speciality  = $_GET['Speciality'];

      require_once('db_config.php');

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM doctor WHERE Speciality='".$Speciality."'";

      $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

      $res = mysqli_fetch_array($r);

      $result = array();

      array_push($result,array(
      "Name"=>$res['Name'],
      "Speciality"=>$res['Speciality'],
      "Hospital"=>$res['Hospital']


        )
          );

         echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

         mysqli_close($con);

           }
```

The php works fine when I type the address on my web browser so am convinced the problem is on the activity but I dont know where. Here is my main Activity.

```
      public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


//For the appointments
public static final String DATA_URL = "http://XXXXX.com/doctor.php?Speciality=";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "Name";
public static final String KEY_SPECIALITY = "Speciality";
public static final String KEY_HOSPITAL = "Hospital";

public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result";

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




    textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);

       }

private void getData() {
    Spinner spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerdoctor);
    String doctor = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();


    textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);
    if (doctor.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter an id", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Please wait...","Fetching...",false,false);

    String url = DATA_URL+doctor;

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            loading.dismiss();
            showJSON(response);
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Could not connect. Please try again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    loading.cancel();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void showJSON(String response){
    String Name="";
    String Speciality="";
    String Hospital = "";
    textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);
        JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(0);
        Name = collegeData.getString(KEY_NAME);
        Speciality = collegeData.getString(KEY_SPECIALITY);
        Hospital = collegeData.getString(KEY_HOSPITAL);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    textViewResult.setText("Name:\t"+Name+"\nSpeciality:\t" +Speciality+ "\nHospital:\t"+ Hospital);
}


public void loaddocs(View v) {
    getData();
}
```

And my logcat

```
       07-21 10:54:30.629 4221-4221/com.kirathe.mos.afriemergency 

W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value .<!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
07-21 10:54:30.631 4221-4221/com.kirathe.mos.afriemergency W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
07-21 10:54:30.631 4221-4221/com.kirathe.mos.afriemergency W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
07-21 10:54:30.631 4221-4221/com.kirathe.mos.afriemergency W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
07-21 10:54:30.631 4221-4221/com.kirathe.mos.afriemergency W/System.err:     at com.kirathe.mos.afriemergency.MainActivity.showJSON(MainActivity.java:389)
07-21 10:54:30.631 4221-4221/com.kirathe.mos.afriemergency W/System.err:     at com.kirathe.mos.afriemergency.MainActivity.access$100(MainActivity.java:45)
07-21 10:54:30.631 4221-4221/com.kirathe.mos.afriemergency W/System.err:     at com.kirathe.mos.afriemergency.MainActivity$2.onResponse(MainActivity.java:368)
07-21 10:54:30.631 4221-4221/com.kirathe.mos.afriemergency W/System.err:     at com.kirathe.mos.afriemergency.MainActivity$2.onResponse(MainActivity.java:364)
07-21 10:54:30.632 4221-4221/com.kirathe.mos.afriemergency W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
07-21 10:54:30.632 4221-4221/com.kirathe.mos.afriemergency W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
07-21 10:54:30.632 4221-4221/com.kirathe.mos.afriemergency W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
07-21 10:54:30.632 4221-4221/com.kirathe.mos.afriemergency W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
07-21 10:54:30.632 4221-4221/com.kirathe.mos.afriemergency W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-21 10:54:30.632 4221-4221/com.kirathe.mos.afriemergency W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
07-21 10:54:30.632 4221-4221/com.kirathe.mos.afriemergency W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
07-21 10:54:30.632 4221-4221/com.kirathe.mos.afriemergency W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-21 10:54:30.632 4221-4221/com.kirathe.mos.afriemergency W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-21 10:54:30.632 4221-4221/com.kirathe.mos.afriemergency W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
07-21 10:54:30.632 4221-4221/com.kirathe.mos.afriemergency W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
```

Comment: What is the output of the webservice? Is it returning any error?

Comment: What is the content type / html output?

Comment: Seems to me that you've forgotten to set the header of the response to be JSON, and you're getting HTML response, which in turn cannot be parsed into JSON by your Android app. Log the response in Android studio before trying to parse it to see what you're getting (`Log.i("tag", response.toString());`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267910/jsonexception-value-of-type-java-lang-string-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonobject?rq=1 see this..

Comment: you are getting response is incorrect. So that response will be html form.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your php script and give it a try

```
<?php

header('Content-type: application/json');

?>
```

Comment: Hey Houssam. It dint work,,I got the general idea and was able to solve the problem though! Thanks☺