# org.json.JSONException: Value test( of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json, mobile

I am getting the following error :

```
org.json.JSONException: Value test( of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

 07-18 18:58:11.424 25827-25827/com.adeel.android.flightdemo W/System.err:      org.json.JSONException: Value test( of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
 07-18 18:58:11.424 25827-25827/com.adeel.android.flightdemo W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
 07-18 18:58:11.424 25827-25827/com.adeel.android.flightdemo W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
 07-18 18:58:11.424 25827-25827/com.adeel.android.flightdemo W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
 07-18 18:58:11.424 25827-25827/com.adeel.android.flightdemo W/System.err:     at com.adeel.android.flightdemo.FlightDataModel.onPostExecute(FlightDataModel.java:86)
 07-18 18:58:11.424 25827-25827/com.adeel.android.flightdemo W/System.err:     at com.adeel.android.flightdemo.FlightDataModel.onPostExecute(FlightDataModel.java:21)
 07-18 18:58:11.424 25827-25827/com.adeel.android.flightdemo W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
 07-18 18:58:11.424 25827-25827/com.adeel.android.flightdemo W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
 07-18 18:58:11.424 25827-25827/com.adeel.android.flightdemo W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
 07-18 18:58:11.424 25827-25827/com.adeel.android.flightdemo W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 07-18 18:58:11.424 25827-25827/com.adeel.android.flightdemo W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
 07-18 18:58:11.424 25827-25827/com.adeel.android.flightdemo W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
 07-18 18:58:11.424 25827-25827/com.adeel.android.flightdemo W/System.err:          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 07-18 18:58:11.424 25827-25827/com.adeel.android.flightdemo W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
 07-18 18:58:11.424 25827-25827/com.adeel.android.flightdemo W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
 07-18 18:58:11.424 25827-25827/com.adeel.android.flightdemo W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

The line which I am getting this error is :

```
 JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
```

Here is my code:

```
 import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.util.Log;

 import org.json.JSONArray;
 import org.json.JSONException;
 import org.json.JSONObject;

 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
      import java.net.MalformedURLException;
 import java.net.URL;


 public class FlightDataModel extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{


    private String data = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550?api_key=f1d314280284e94ff7d1feeed7d44fdf&callback=test";

URL mURL;
HttpURLConnection mHttpURLConnection;
String result = "" ;
String main;
JSONArray mArray = null;
private String mImageIcon;
private String movieTitle;
private String movieDesc;
private String movieRating;


@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

    try {

        Log.d("FlightDemo", "doInBackground method called");
        mURL = new URL(data);
        mHttpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)mURL.openConnection();
        mHttpURLConnection.connect();
        InputStream inputStream = mHttpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

        int data = inputStreamReader.read();

        while (data != -1){

            char current = (char) data;

            result += current;

           data = inputStreamReader.read();

        }



    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return result;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

    //What to do when the doInBackground Method is executed..

    try {

        //JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);

        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);

       // JSONArray array = new JSONArray(result);



        Log.d("FlightDemo", object.toString());




    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    super.onPostExecute(s);
}

public String getImageIcon() {
    return mImageIcon;
}

public String getMovieTitle() {
    return movieTitle;
}

public String getMovieDesc() {
    return movieDesc;
}

public String getMovieRating() {
    return movieRating;
}

public String getData() {
    return data;
}
 }
```

I have been working on this code for a few days.. I am a beginner in android app development. So any help is much appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: Can you please check if you string is in the format new JSONObject("{your string}"). Same question has been asked before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267910/jsonexception-value-of-type-java-lang-string-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonobject

Comment: Looks like you're new here. Welcome! People are reluctant to help if you don't show what you have tried and reduce the code you present to the bare minimum amount that still shows the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There might be some special/invisible characters in your json string. You can print the result string before converting to JSONObject or open it in some editor to display hidden characters and see if the json is proper. You can also use UTF 8 standards for the input stream.