# JSON error:value <!doctype of type java.lang.string cannot be converted to jsonobject

Tags: android

On my android API , I'm getting below error

> JSON Error: java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

here comes my json response string

```
objjson.Append("{")
objjson.Append("""error""")
objjson.Append(":")
objjson.Append("false")
objjson.Append(",")
objjson.Append("""SyncFlag""")
objjson.Append(":")
objjson.Append("""Y""")
objjson.Append(",")
objjson.Append("""SyncTime""")
objjson.Append(":")
objjson.Append("""" & gen.dateConvertwithtime(System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")) & """")
objjson.Append(",")
objjson.Append("""SyncStatus""")
objjson.Append(":")
objjson.Append("""Success""")
objjson.Append("}")
Response.Clear()
Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
Response.Write(objjson.ToString())
Response.End()
.Parameters.Clear()
Exit Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSONException: Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267910/jsonexception-value-of-type-java-lang-string-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonobject)

Comment: paste your backend script URL in a browser to see what it actually returns

Comment: <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField2" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField3" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField4" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField5" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField6" runat="server" />