# Json parsing error canot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, json

Hi I am trying to get JSON from url to ListItem where I want to show it.
But I am getting error like:

> json parsing error: value 48600123456 at 0 of type java.lang.String
>   cannot be converted to JSONObject.

There is part of code:

```
@Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("phones");

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                       String name= c.getString("name");
                       String phone = c.getString("phone");
                       String phone2 = c.getString("phone2");

                        // tmp hash map for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        contact.put("name", name);
                        contact.put("phone", phone);
                        contact.put("pone2", phone2);

                        //adding contact to contact list
                        contactList.add(contact);
                    }
```

And there is my JSON.

> {"phones":["phone: 48600123456","phone2: 48600234532","phone3: 48600567234"]}

What is wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSONException: Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267910/jsonexception-value-of-type-java-lang-string-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonobject)

Comment: Given Json does not match with your code, Are you sure this is the correct json.

Comment: Why are you downvoting every one's answer? Did you didn't understand them or what ?

Comment: @VivekMishra not me...

Comment: What did you expect `c.getString("name");` to do? Where's the name key in the JSON you've shown? Try to understand JSON parsing, boot copy examples when you have completely different data

Comment: @cricket_007 I changed my JSON to name: value, etc..

Comment: Then can you please edit your question to show the new JSON?

Comment: @cricket_007 done

Comment: See updated answer

Answer (score 2):

The method fails at the first iteration of

```
JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
```

because, according to the json given in input, the variable `contacts` is an array of `String` ("48600123456","48600234532","48600567234"), not of `JSONObject`

This is the way to parse the given json:

```
...

// Getting JSON Array node
JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("phones");

// looping through All Contacts
for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
    String value = contacts.getString(i);

    ...
}
```

Comment: How it should looks like?

Comment: @Defus there's a `getString(i)` method. Did you try?

Comment: Yes but then I can't do:  String phone = c.getString("phone"); because Cannot resolve method

Comment: @Defus, no... Delete `c`. That's where the error is. It's `contacts.getString(number)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to index the array by the correct type. Each value is a string, so use `getString`. Otherwise, you just use `get`, and cast the Object later.

Honestly, I think you should be using just a List for the phones, not a map, but this is the correct code that you're trying to do

```
// Getting JSON Array node
JSONArray phones = jsonObj.getJSONArray("phones");

// tmp hash map for single contact 
Map<String, String> phoneMap = new HashMap<>();

// adding each phone to HashMap key => value 
for (int i =0; i < phones.getLength(); i++) {
    phoneMap.put("phone"+i, phones.getString(i));
} 

//adding phones to contact list
contactList.add(phoneMap);
```

Might be worth it to actually define a `Contact` object. Then you can try using Gson, for example, to parse the JSON for you

**EDIT**

`"name: value"` is still **one string**. If you want an array of JSON objects, you must have `{}` on the outside, and keys need `[{"phone": "48600123456", "phone2": "48600234532"}]`

If you format it, you can clearly see the difference.

```
{
    "phones": ["phone: 48600123456", "phone2: 48600234532", "phone3: 48600567234"]
}
```

vs

```
{
    "phones": [{
        "phone": "48600123456",
        "phone2": "48600234532",
        "phone3": "48600567234"
    }]
}
```

vs

```
{
    "phones": [{
            "phone": "48600123456"
        },
        {
            "phone": "48600234532"
        },
        {
            "phone": "48600567234"
        }
    ]
}
```

Personally, I see nothing wrong with the first way you posted, which is what the code above assumes

```
{
    "phones": ["48600123456", "48600234532", "48600567234"]
}
```

Comment: but in future if counts increases then loop will be better

Comment: Unhandled exception org.JSON.JSONException

Comment: @Vivek Fixed it

Comment: @Defus. The top message of an exception doesn't tell me anything

Comment: @cricket_007 First line: jsonArray phones = jsonObj.getJSONArray - Cannot resolve symbol jsonObj

Comment: @Defus I literally copied that from the question. Might want to paste this code within scope of that variable

Answer (score -1):

You **don't have any JsonObject inside your jsonarray**, that you are trying to parse in your code here

```
for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
 JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
```

Access your strings directly from your array like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
      String contact=contacts.getString(i);
    }
```

Comment: I want all separated

Comment: You can add them in a list then. Create a string type list and them in the list inside the loop

Answer (score -1):

From your code, I think your json structure is such as :

> {"phones":[
>                {"name":"48600123456",
>                 "phone":"48600234532",
>                  "phone2":"48600567234"}]}

Comment: Nah my json is like I pasted

Comment: So `4860012345` means name ? `48600234532` means `phone2`?

Comment: You should also add `"name" : 4860012345` etc like above json.

Comment: I did, but it still doesn't work. Now i got Json parsing error: NO value for phone2

Comment: So you should add `name` and `phone` and `phone2`