# JSONObject don't Get data from QR code

Tags: java, android, json

When I scan QR code it's getting a data on `result.getContents` but didn't pass the data on JSONObject `obj` just directing go on `Catch` block

data get pass to this line `JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result.getContents());` but when start to `Debug` then its not pass the data on 'obj' in above line.

here is my code :

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (result != null) {
            //if qrcode has nothing in it
            if (result.getContents() == null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Result Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                //if qr contains data
                try {
                    //converting the data to json
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result.getContents());
                    //setting values to textviews

                    if(obj.has("FN")) {
                        etFirstName.setText(obj.getString("FN"));
                    }
                    if(obj.has("N")) {
                        etLastName.setText(obj.getString("LN"));
                    }
                    if(obj.has("TITLE")) {
                        etTitle.setText(obj.getString("TITLE"));
                    }
                    if(obj.has("STATUS")) {
                        etStatus.setText(obj.getString("STATUS"));
                    }
                    if(obj.has("EMAIL")) {
                        etEmail.setText(obj.getString("EMAIL"));
                    }
                    if(obj.has("TEL;TYPE=work")) {
                        etPhoneHome.setText(obj.getString("TEL;TYPE=work"));
                    }
                    if(obj.has("TEL;TYPE=cell")) {
                        etPhonePrimary.setText(obj.getString("TEL;TYPE=cell"));
                    }
                    if(obj.has("ADR;TYPE=work")) {
                        etAddressLine1.setText(obj.getString("ADR;TYPE=work"));
                    }
                    if(obj.has("Street")) {
                        etAddressLine2.setText(obj.getString("Street"));
                    }
                    if(obj.has("Street")) {
                        etCity.setText(obj.getString("Street"));
                    }
                    if(obj.has("zip")) {
                        etZip.setText(obj.getString("zip"));
                    }


                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    Log.e(TAG, "notification= error" + e.toString());
                    e.printStackTrace();

                    /*etFirstName.setText(result.getContents());
                    etLastName.setText(result.getContents());
                    etTitle.setText(result.getContents());
                    etEmail.setText(result.getContents());*/
                    //if control comes here
                    //that means the encoded format not matches
                    //in this case you can display whatever data is available on the qrcode
                    //to a toast
                    Toast.makeText(this, result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

Logcat see below :

```
03-09 11:23:06.909 297-678/? E/SimpleSoftOMXComponent: 3
03-09 11:23:07.127 297-665/? E/audio_a2dp_hw: adev_set_parameters: ERROR: set param called even when stream out is null
03-09 11:23:12.899 26980-26980/com.example.crm E/AddContactActivity: notification= errororg.json.JSONException: Value BEGIN of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
03-09 11:23:13.040 297-8371/? E/SimpleSoftOMXComponent: 1
03-09 11:23:13.040 297-8371/? E/SimpleSoftOMXComponent: 2
03-09 11:23:13.041 297-8371/? E/SimpleSoftOMXComponent: 3
```

JSON Response Data like below code:

```
BEGIN:VCARD,
VERSION:2.1
FN:sss sss
N:sss;sss
TITLE:PHD
TEL;CELL:1111111111
TEL;WORK;VOICE:2222222222
TEL;HOME;VOICE:8888888888
EMAIL;HOME;INTERNET:abc@example.com
EMAIL;WORK;INTERNET:abc@example.com
URL:http://ABC@ABC.COM
ADR:;;sample address;ss;;102103;US
ORG:ss
END:VCARD
```

Search everywhere but I don't get any result for this problem so plzzz help me:)

Thanks&Regards 
Sandeep Patel

Comment: Can you please show me logcat error

Comment: JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result.getContents()); //<<<
text entire json response here what you have getting after scanning QR.

Comment: see logcat @PankajMundra

Comment: I scan QR and get data but data pass on `Catch` block not show in my fields @Radhey

Comment: I'm talking about the json response.paste it here.

Comment: i past the Json response @Radhey

Comment: first validate your json response online (for ex : https://jsoneditoronline.org/) . your response is not in proper format.

Comment: data send me a QR code how i am change the data ? @Radhey

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166515/discussion-between-radhey-and-sandeep-patel).

Comment: your reponse is not valid JSON, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267910/jsonexception-value-of-type-java-lang-string-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonobject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is not JSON, see what [JSONLint reports](https://jsonlint.com/?json=BEGIN%3AVCARD%2C%20VERSION%3A2.1%20FN%3Asss%20sss%20N%3Asss%3Bsss%20TITLE%3APHD%20TEL%3BCELL%3A1111111111%20TEL%3BWORK%3BVOICE%3A2222222222%20TEL%3BHOME%3BVOICE%3A8888888888%20EMAIL%3BHOME%3BINTERNET%3Aabc%40example.com%20EMAIL%3BWORK%3BINTERNET%3Aabc%40example.com%20URL%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2FABC%40ABC.COM%20ADR%3A%3B%3Bsample%20address%3Bss%3B%3B102103%3BUS%20ORG%3Ass%20END%3AVCARD) on your output. The `errororg.json.JSONException` informs you, that in the beginning of your string, the phrase "BEGIN" is not allowed in Json.

```
{
    "json": "looks like this",
    "key": "value"
}
```

As your data seems to be vCard, you need a different parsing library, e.g. https://github.com/mangstadt/ez-vcard

```
String str =
"BEGIN:VCARD\r\n" +
"VERSION:4.0\r\n" +
"N:Doe;Jonathan;;Mr;\r\n" +
"FN:John Doe\r\n" +
"END:VCARD\r\n";

VCard vcard = Ezvcard.parse(str).first();
String fullName = vcard.getFormattedName().getValue();
String lastName = vcard.getStructuredName().getFamily();
```

So in your code snippet:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (result != null) {
        //if qrcode has nothing in it
        if (result.getContents() == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Result Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            //if qr contains data
            try {
                //converting the data to vCard object
                VCard vcard = Ezvcard.parse(result.getContents()).first();
                //setting values to textviews

                // "given name" is the first name
                etFirstName.setText(vcard.getStructuredName().getGiven());

                // "family name" is the last name
                etLastName.setText(vcard.getStructuredName().getFamily());
                ...
```

Comment: if i want to set `TITLE` and `STATUS` so how to i set ??

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution for you.
        If you getting response data like

```
        "
        BEGIN:VCARD,
        VERSION:2.1
        FN:sss sss
        N:sss;sss
        TITLE:PHD
        TEL;CELL:1111111111
        TEL;WORK;VOICE:2222222222
        TEL;HOME;VOICE:8888888888
        EMAIL;HOME;INTERNET:abc@example.com
        EMAIL;WORK;INTERNET:abc@example.com
        URL:http://ABC@ABC.COM
        ADR:;;sample address;ss;;102103;US
        ORG:ss
        END:VCARD
        " this than forgot the json object concept.
```

Use the vcard library. you can get vcard library from here 
             https://github.com/mangstadt/ez-vcard

By using this library you can get any contact data you want using below code and you can set in your `editext.`

```
String str =
    "BEGIN:VCARD\r\n" +
    "VERSION:4.0\r\n" +
    "N:Doe;Jonathan;;Mr;\r\n" +
    "FN:John Doe\r\n" +
    "END:VCARD\r\n";`

        VCard vcard = Ezvcard.parse(str).first();
        String fullName = vcard.getFormattedName().getValue();
        String lastName = vcard.getStructuredName().getFamily();
```

Still if you have any doubt how to do this. You can ask me further.

Comment: I want get QR code data not static data  in your example u print static data so it is possible to get  dynamic data

Comment: It will work with dynamic data. If QR code give multiple contact data stilll it will work.  if your qr code generate vcf formated data than it will work for sure.
When you scan the qr code what information it gives?

Comment: This information its give me on catch block toast **`BEGIN:VCARD,
VERSION:2.1
FN:sss sss
N:sss;sss
TITLE:PHD
TEL;CELL:1111111111
TEL;WORK;VOICE:2222222222
TEL;HOME;VOICE:8888888888
EMAIL;HOME;INTERNET:abc@example.com
EMAIL;WORK;INTERNET:abc@example.com
URL:http://ABC@ABC.COM
ADR:;;sample address;ss;;102103;US
ORG:ss
END:VCARD`**

Comment: You are getting this info in catch while executing this line. 

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result.getContents());

but I think you can get the data by result.geContent(). 
No need to parse the json now. After getting data in result.getContent(). You can use this line  VCard vcard = Ezvcard.parse(str).first();
     
   String fullName = vcard.getFormattedName().getValue();
   String lastName = vcard.getStructuredName().getFamily();

You can follow my solution

Comment: yes in this line i'll get data but it's not pass on to the `obj` **Object**

Comment: No need to pass data into obj.
Now use this library  https://github.com/mangstadt/ez-vcard

 VCard vcard = Ezvcard.parse(str).first(); String fullName = vcard.getFormattedName().getValue(); String lastName = vcard.getStructuredName().getFamily();

Answer (score 0):

Check your string data.
Make sure Your String data is json object.

Print in log your string and check whether it is json or not.

Comment: JSONObject not created so i'm stuck hear so u have any solution

Answer (score 0):

The content is not JSON, so you cannot convert it to JSONObject.
You may need a parser for Vcard. Search for some library in Github or write your own.