# Hot to get count of API calls in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I have a simple class (Model) with 3 variables id (p.k and auto increment) url (String) count (int)

Client can add  url and can fetch url by id.
The problem is I need to count how many times each url is been called.

My Pojo ->

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Sortner {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String url;
    private Integer counter;
}
```

Controller ->

```
  @GetMapping("/findById")
    public ResponseEntity<?> findById(Integer id) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(sortnerService.findById(id), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Repo is just extending JpaRepository ..

Service ->

```
public String findById(Integer id) {
        Sortner sortner = new Sortner();
        
        return "no. of times api called =>"+sortner.getCounter()+1  ;
    }
```

That's what I have tried to do but this is not returning response as I wanted its just returning 1 no matter how many times I call api using Swagger (YES the logic is really shit)
I don't know how to resolve this and make it work please help

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Spring Boot Actuator to get the details. It will not only provide the count for the API hits but also provide the duration, status response code any many more details and you can filter them as required.

You just need to add the following dependency in the pom file

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Then make a hit at the given URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/actuator/metrics/http.server.requests
```

You can filter the response using the URI, status and exception as required

```
localhost:8080/actuator/metrics/http.server.requests?tag=uri:<endPoint>
localhost:8080/actuator/metrics/http.server.requests?tag=uri:/user/asset/getAllAssets
localhost:8080/actuator/metrics/http.server.requests?tag=uri:/user/asset/getAllAssets&tag=status:200
```

The response will be as follow

```
{
    "name": "http.server.requests",
    "description": null,
    "baseUnit": "seconds",
    "measurements": [
        {
            "statistic": "COUNT",
            "value": 3
        },
        {
            "statistic": "TOTAL_TIME",
            "value": 0.21817219999999998
        },
        {
            "statistic": "MAX",
            "value": 0.1379249
        }
    ],
    "availableTags": [
        {
            "tag": "exception",
            "values": [
                "MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException",
                "None"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "method",
            "values": [
                "GET"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "uri",
            "values": [
                "/{id}.*",
                "/user/asset/getAsset/{assetId}",
                "/user/asset/getAllAssets"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "outcome",
            "values": [
                "CLIENT_ERROR",
                "SUCCESS"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "status",
            "values": [
                "400",
                "404",
                "200"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

More details have been explained here

[Spring Boot : Count Page Views - Actuators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55332664/10961238)

[Metrics Collection for Spring Boot REST APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56987784/10961238)

In case you want to analyze the API details with the dashboards in more details you can follow the given blogs

[Application Monitoring Using Spring Boot Admin](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/application-monitoring-using-spring-boot-admin-part-2-ed14178c6964)

[Application Monitoring with Prometheus and Grafana](https://medium.com/swlh/application-monitoring-with-prometheus-and-grafana-part-3-1c4ad5e1b042)

Answer (score 0):

Sortner class

```
 public class Sortner {
  Long id;
  URL url;
 }
```

Controller

```
 @GetMapping("/findUrlById")
 public void findSortnerById(Integer id, HttpServletResponse response) throws 
 IOException {
   List<Sortner> urls = sortnerService.findUrlById(id);
   if(urls != null && urls.size() > 0) {
       response.sendRedirect(urls.get(0).getUrl().toString());
   }
     response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND)
   }
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendError(int) redirects to the required URL
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendError(int) response.sendError returns 404 as the URL cannot be found in the database

Comment: But I want to increase y counter variable everytime client hit the endpoint ? can you suggest something about that ! thanks

Comment: I got it, just an example that I wrote

Comment: It seems like this will only give me url as res. there is no use if counter var to be increased