# How do I retrieve certain metrics in my code Like the number of calls of a particular endpoint with spring-boot actuator?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-micrometer

I need to determine how many times my GET /users endpoint is called during the last hour.
My first thought was to use a counter and increment it everytime there is a call and rest every 3600 seconds.

Then I found that spring actuator can help provide this if filter using the URI :

```
localhost:8080/actuator/metrics/http.server.requests?tag=uri:/users
```

Response:

```
{
    "name": "http.server.requests",
    "description": null,
    "baseUnit": "seconds",
    "measurements": [
        {
            "statistic": "COUNT",
            "value": 3
        },
        {
            "statistic": "TOTAL_TIME",
            "value": 0.21817219999999998
        }
        
}
```

Here I called /users 3 times.

My question is, how do I retrieve those values in my code?
Can anyone point me to an example? Thanks

Comment: What version of Boot are you using? You can just auto wire the `MeterRegistry` and ask it. But it might not know stats for a whole hour. You likely need to register your own meter registry to track over an hour.

Comment: Thanks Boris for the answer. I am using spring 2.0.4. I see, I will have to create my own metric then. I didn't find many examples out there. Do you think it is better to use a simple method like a counter instead of using spring boot actuator?

Comment: Depends whether you want it fast and correct or easy I suppose.

Comment: Here is an example to get count based on the endpoint using the spring boot actuator. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55354671/10961238 If you want it to be based on duration then I think you need to create a custom impl.