# Attempting to create JSONObject from String with Java (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, json

I have run into an issue where I try to parse a serialised json string to a JSONObject to later retrieve key values for another object, PetFedInfo.  I make the called from my android app to an ASP.NET web API and the string returns successfully.

Here is the code where I parse the result from the asp.net api server:

```
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
    try {

        String stringFromServer =  PostHTTP(Constants.POST_PET_GETFEDINFO,jObj);
        Log.v("stringFromServer",stringFromServer);
        Log.v("directCallResult",PostHTTP(Constants.POST_PET_GETFEDINFO,jObj));
        Log.v("actualString","{\"petName\":\"nn\",\"lastFedTime\":\"\"}");

        jsonObj = new JSONObject("{\"petName\":\"nn\",\"lastFedTime\":\"\"}");
        Log.v("jsonObjFromManualString",jsonObj.toString());
        jsonObj = new JSONObject(PostHTTP(Constants.POST_PET_GETFEDINFO,jObj));
        Log.v("jsonObjFromDirectCall",jsonObj.toString());

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

After I run the app in debug mode, the string from the instance 'stringFromServer' (Logged as 'stringFromServer') throws an error when I attempt to create a JSONObject:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value {"petName":"mm","lastFedTime":""} of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
        at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:112)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:168)
        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:181)
        at com.FeedMyPet.helper.WebRequestManager$2.run(WebRequestManager.java:102)
```

Whereas the string where I manually enter (logged as 'actualString') successfully creates the JSON object.  I have printed out all string values to the console using Log.v and they almost have the same output

```
V/stringFromServer: "{\"petName\":\"v\",\"lastFedTime\":\"\"}"
V/directCallResult: "{\"petName\":\"v\",\"lastFedTime\":\"\"}"
V/actualString: {"petName":"nn","lastFedTime":""}
```

I have reviewed the construction for JSONObject and it accepts a String:

```
    public JSONObject(String json) throws JSONException {
        this(new JSONTokener(json));
    }
```

I'm a little lost as to why the serialised object using quotation marks (no object?) successfully creates the object, and a String instance cannot.  How can I get the String object to match the result of 'actualString'?

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: jsonObj.put(key, value);

Comment: that is not an answer to what I am asking.  I am having issues generating a JSONObject via a constructor string.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean the string received from the server. There might be some hidden characters added to it.

Have a you look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/15469907/578855

You can also try to replace the double quotes with this

`json=json.replace("\\\"","'");`

Comment: Hello, yes I have had tried this.  I have tried:

`code`
String stringFromServer =  PostHTTP(Constants.POST_PET_GETFEDINFO,jObj);
jsonObj = new JSONObject(stringFromServer.substring(stringFromServer.indexOf("{"), stringFromServer.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));
`code`

and get this:
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Expected literal value at character 1 of {\"petName\":\"vv\",\"lastFedTime\":\"\"}