# Value Failed of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, json

I am getting error in the food delivery app while placing an order

```
public void resultAlert(String HasilProses) {
        Log.e("HasilProses", HasilProses);

        
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(HasilProses);

            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("ORDER_PLACED");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String error = object.getString("error");
                int order_id = Integer.parseInt(object.getString("order_id"));
                Constant_Api.order_id = order_id;
                String message = object.getString("message");

                
                dbhelper.deleteAllData();
                if (payable>0) {
                    startPayment();
                }
                else{
                    lytOrder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    txtAlert.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    paymentUpdate("0");
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

my `Logcat` error  and `JSON` response

```
 Failed{
    "ORDER_PLACED": [
        {
            "error": "true",
            "message": "Failed"
        }
    ]
}
```

> W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value Failed of type
> java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
>
> W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:112)
> at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:168)
>
> W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:181)

Comment: Do share string value of HasilProses

Comment: // HasilProses is just a string paased in the constructor as shown below

public void resultAlert(String HasilProses) {

  // here is the code which is shown above

}

Comment: What is its value

Comment: i am a newbie here is the file 
http://testingapimsf.tk/problem/ActivityCart.java

Comment: What this lines printed Log.e("HasilProses", HasilProses);

Comment: Hey Priyanka Thanks for Taking Interest i am newbie dont know why it is printed Can you reach me on whatsapp +918931863425  , If possible , even if you want i'll Pay you for resolving this .... Once again thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSONException: Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267910/jsonexception-value-of-type-java-lang-string-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonobject)